# Direct HDFS access in hadooponazure

Tags: azure, hadoop, hdfs

Crosspost from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/5030259c-3255-4aa7-a348-e102c007ce0d/

I'm checking pre-release service https://www.hadooponazure.com. Beside usual job execution I'd like to have access to HDFS from my app. I'm trying to run it right on name node, available through RDP.

I've tried stahdard Java HDFS driver (opened with the org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get() method), including the name node configuration ('C:\Apps\dist\conf') into classpath. As far as I understand this should be enought to connect my app to HDFS cluster the same way as the name node do.

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException; Host Details : local host is: "RD00155D42B620/10.*.*.*"; destination host is: ""10.*.*.*":9000;
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:724)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1090)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:193)
        at $Proxy6.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:65)
        at $Proxy6.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:725)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1165)
        at org.gridgain.examples.dataload.GridCacheHdfsDataLoaderExample.populateHdfs(GridCacheHdfsDataLoaderExample.java:225)
        at org.gridgain.examples.dataload.GridCacheHdfsDataLoaderExample.main(GridCacheHdfsDataLoaderExample.java:93)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:818)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:756)
```

(where 10.*.*.* is ip of the name node, where I'm runing my app).

I think this connection failure caused by some kind of Azure's internal policy.

So I have two main questions:

1. Are external connection to HDFS somehow supported in this service?
2. Am I right trying to connect to HDFS using name node's configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates, from my experience, that there is a version mismatch between the Hadoop libraries deployed on the server (Azure side) and the version you are attempting to run your code with.